# Find a basis of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by the equation $−6x−7y+8z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I tried to solve this by solving for $x$ where $x$ is
$$-7/6y + 4/3z.$$
After this I substituted the value of $x$ to get 
$$-6 (-7/6y + 4/3z) - 7y + 8z.$$
Taking $y$ and $z$ gave me $[7 -7 0]$ and $[-8 0 8]$.

But this is not the right answer and I do not know the right answer. Can someone please help me on what I did wrong?

Comment: That’s clearly incorrect since neither vector satisfies the equation. Why did you “substitute the value of $x$” back into the original equation? After simplifying, you end up with $0=0$, which gets you nowhere.

Comment: But I thought it was supposed to be 0 =0 at the end

Comment: That just means that your solution for $x$ in terms of the other two variables was correct. Substituting back into the original equation doesn’t help you find specific values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ that solve it, which is what you’re after here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, $x= -(7/6)y+ (4/3)z$.  But what do you mean by "taking $y$ and $z$"?

If you take $y= 1$, $z= 0$ you get $(-7/6, 1, 0)$. Taking $y= 0$, $z= 1$, $(4/3, 0, 1)$.
If you don't like fractions, $(-7, 6, 0)$ and $(4, 0, 3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very generous hint. The solution set of your equation consists of vectors $((-7/6)y+(4/3)z,y,z),$ with $y$ and $z$ arbitrary. If you set $y=1$ and $z=0$ you get the vector $(-7/6,1,0).$ Reversing the values for $y$ and $z$ yields $(4/3,0,1).$ Can you show these vectors are linearly independent? Can you write an arbitrary solution (as stated above) in terms of them?